# How to remove fan and cooler from motherboard?

Tags: fan, cpu-cooler

I have  mb ECS 945GCT-M2 and want to remove fan and cooler in order to clean them, but I can't see any screw or something to make them off.

Any help pls, and any additional advice ?

[here is the picture:](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&docid=JS2xt5fThYSHzM&tbnid=SdfuUBanyux6zM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http://www.dealfish.co.th/product-4234105/gallery/?p=3&item_id=4234105&ei=kBfqUtn5KsKctQbyv4D4Cg&psig=AFQjCNGOwS5KarjLS8lRZKtzS_090Xr-Vg&ust=1391159552595509)

Comment: Do you have new thermal compound because you'll need it if you remove the cooler from the CPU.  What are you trying to clean, dust?  Do you have a hair dry that has a cool setting?  I would blow on it with that and your breath; its dusty but safer than removing things and putting them back.  An air compressor with blow gun attachment is better; just hold the fan so you don't spin the blades up too much.  Other than that, there should be 4 pins that you can pull up on or something.  Worst case is you remove the motherboard from the case and then it should become obvious of how remove the cooler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below guide step by step:
[image: fan guide]

Also you can use [this link](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-032258.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot separate heat sink and fan from each other. However you can detach them from motherboard to reveal CPU beneath it.

To do this, find four pins around the heat sink. On their top, there should be a small ridge and also an arrow near it.

Put a screwdriver/fingernail in that ridge and twist that pin in arrow's direction.

Repeat above step to all four pins.

Now turn the board around and you should find four locks (now unlocked) which are at the other end of those four pins.

Simply press those ends upwards and heat sink + fan assembly should be separated. (Make sure you unplug the connector first)

If you already have done above and you want to separate heat sink from fan, you shouldn't do that. Since both are attached to each other, no dust can enter between them. Use a powerful blower to clean whole unit.

Comment: Or just refer above answer.. :-)